# Lock-screen iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-3gs

My question is quite simple (I think and hope). I would like to know what happens when I lock my phone.
I made a little clock-like app which should play and loop a sound at a given moment (lets say 18:00). But when I press the power button, and the phone locks, nothing happens at 18:00. When I press the power button again 18:05 and the "lock screen" shows, then the sound is played.

Please note, I didn't return to the home screen before locking the phone. The app is still open, when I unlock the app is shown.
Is there some way to let the app still do its thing eventhough I locked the screen? Or is this just a programming error I might have made?

Regards,
Paul Peelen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at information about the application delegate’s applicationWillResignActive: and applicationDidBecomeActive: methods.  You can find this information in the iPhone Application Programming Guide.  Also, take a look at information about "The Automatic Sleep Timer" in the same guide.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW59

I think you can answer most of your own questions with this information but please post any follow up questions that you might have.

Bart

Comment: great, didn't think of that. I will take a look at it tonight. Thanks in advance!

Regards, Paul

Comment: Hi Paul,

Just checking to see if this worked out for you?  

Bart

Comment: It seemed for a while that this issue was solved, but the alarm still rings 10 - 15 minutes to late. I fixed it using a function how to disallow the phone to go to sleep mode.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found a solution!